# How to get virtualenv to run Python 3 instead of Python 2.7?

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, virtualenv

On Mac, if I simply open a new terminal window and run:

```
python --version
```

I get:

```
3.6
```

but if I do this:

```
 virtualenv venv && source venv/bin/activate
```

and then, in that environment, I run :

```
python --version
```

I get:

```
2.7
```

I need virtualenv to run 3.6. How do I do that?

This :

```
/usr/bin/python
```

is 2.7 but this:

```
/usr/local/bin/python
```

is 3.6. The path for my normal user has `/usr/local/bin` come up before `/usr/bin/`. Is virtualenv running as someone else? How do I control its path?

I ran this:

```
virtualenv -p /usr/local//Cellar/python/3.6.5/bin/python3 venv
```

but then I do this:

```
virtualenv venv && source venv/bin/activate
```

and I'm running in an environment with 2.7.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

On Python 3 you don't need `virtualenv` script anymore, you should just use the venv module included with standard lib:

```
python3 -m venv myvenv
```

But if you really want to keep using the old `virtualenv` script, you can - specify the interpreter explicitly with the `-p` option:

```
virtualenv -p /path/to/python3 myvenv
```

Comment: I tried this but it seems to have no effect: `virtualenv -p /usr/local//Cellar/python/3.6.5/bin/python3 venv`

Comment: What do you mean "no effect"? Describe the actual result and how it differs from expected result.

Comment: Because you ran virtualenv again afterward, undoing the previous venv and putting another 2.7 one in place!  Instead of `virtualenv venv && source venv/bin/activate` just do the `source myvenv/bin/activate`.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to change `python` globally to Python3 as I think you're using it more often than Python 2.7 (or hopefully always). To achieve this, add the following line of code at the end of your `.bash_profile`:

```
alias python='python3'
```

**virtuanenv** is using */usr/bin/python*, hence it should work now.

If you don't want to change it globally, than you should use the following command to create your Python3.6 virtual environment:

```
python3 -m venv venv
```

or the explicit Python version if you have multiple Python3 versions installed:

```
python3.6 -m venv venv
```

On more suggestion at the end: I recommend you to read something about **pipenv** as it's the new recommended way to handle virtual environments and your whole package management at once. It's super easy and fixes a lot of common issues. [Here's](https://realpython.com/pipenv-guide/) a nice article from realpython.com on that topic.

Hope I could help you. Have a nice day.

Comment: Not matter what I did it always installed PY2. The version number trick there really helped me out. Obviously just `python3` did not.